# How to override application-test.yml in spring boot test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have src/main/test/resources/application-test.yml, as per SpringBootTest it will load application.yml and then loads application-test.yml. But I face a scenario where I want to override certain properties in application-test.yml only for one test but other test needs to use properties from application-test.yml. How would I do this ?

I tried to use the `@TestPropertySource` annotation to override but it is not working.

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= MyApplicationTestApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-test.yml",
                                    "classpath:file-test.properties"})
```

Comment: for this `Now again I want to override certain properties` you can use `application-test.yml` right?

Comment: I am using the application-test.yml already. Question is how to override properties in application-test.yml as there is a need that I want certain properties to be override only for one of my test.

Comment: The `@TestPropertySource` overrides everything else. So just add that with only the `file-test.properties` and leave the `@ActiveProfile`. Spring will bootstrap a new context based on that and with the sepcial settings. YOu probably don't need `@DirtiesContext` unless you want everything to restart before each test.

Comment: @M.Deinum file-test.properties is not considered while Spring bootstraps. Also using DirtiesContext as I need it to restart as beans that are mocked differs for each test.

Comment: Why would you need an `@DirtiesContext` for that. `@MockBean` instances are already placed in the context. Is the properties file in the class path? As it really should be taken into account.  Looks like you are doing things that you shouldn't be doing and thus breaks bootstrapping code.

Comment: @DirtiesContext is there as I have multiple tests, with each test having mocks on diff beans and dont want to share context for test , so each test are cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for comments and answer , just wanted to add which worked for me

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "some.property=localhost:9094")
```

[Link to doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--)

Answer (score 2):

What about creating one more profile and activate both of them (order matters) `@ActiveProfiles({"test", "test-override"})`

Or you can just override using System.properties, for example in static block, before spring context starts loading itself.

Comment: I dont want another profile to be created. but it worked though. but this worked.

Comment: although this worked, but having a profile just for overriding properties so instead this worked for me `@SpringBootTest(properties = "some.property=localhost:9094") `